# How to find $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_{2n}}{n^3}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_{2n}^{(2)}}{n^2}$ using real methods?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, harmonic-numbers, polylogarithm

How to calculate

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_{2n}}{n^3}$$

and

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_{2n}^{(2)}}{n^2}$$

by means of real methods?

This question was suggested by **Cornel** the author of the book, *Almost Impossible Integrals, Sums and Series*.

The way I would approach the problem is to use the series property:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n f(2n)=\Re \sum_{n=1}^\infty i^n f(n),$$ namely

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_{2n}}{n^3}=8\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_{2n}}{(2n)^3}=8\Re\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{i^n H_n}{n^3}$$

then we use the well-known generating function $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^nH_n}{n^3}$. But this method is really tedious as we will need to use $\Re\{\text{Li}_2(1+i), \text{Li}_3(1+i),\text{Li}_4(1+i),\text{Li}_4(\frac{1+i}{2})\}.$

By the way, I have not seen a rigorous proof of the following [equality](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3290798):

$$\operatorname{Re} \operatorname{Li}_4 (1 + i)= -\frac{5}{16} \operatorname{Li}_4 \left (\frac{1}{2} \right ) + \frac{97}{9216} \pi^4 + \frac{\pi^2}{48} \ln^2 2 - \frac{5}{384} \ln^4 2\tag1$$

So solving this sum in a different way would be considered a new rigorous proof of $(1)$.

For the second series, I would follow the same approach.

Any idea by real methods? Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**A (revolutionary) solution by Cornel Ioan Valean**

The series in this post are some of the toughest harmonic series ever known in the mathematical literature, and to my best knowledge, up to this moment except a solution involving contour integration by **Song** (for the first series), there is no known solution that is built on simple real means. Also, the present cocktail of
simple ideas opens the road to calculate other **very advanced integrals and series** by real methods and extract polylogarithmic values involving a complex argument as mentioned in the main post.

Based on the Fourier-like series in the book, **(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series**, page $248$, eq. $3.292$, we have

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(2H_{2n}-2H_n+\frac{1}{2n}-2\log(2)\right)\frac{\sin^2(2nx)}{n}=\log(\sin(x))\log(\cos(x)), \ 0< x<\frac{\pi}{2}.$$

The **BIG magical trick** here is to note that

$$\log(\sin(x))\log(\cos(x))=\frac{1}{4} \log ^2\left(\frac{1}{2} \sin (2 x)\right)-\frac{1}{4} \log ^2(\tan (x)),$$
and this simple fact makes a huge difference as you'll see.

Then, the Fourier-like series above can be written as

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(2H_{2n}-2H_n+\frac{1}{2n}-2\log(2)\right)\frac{\sin^2(2nx)}{n}=\frac{1}{4} \log ^2\left(\frac{1}{2} \sin (2 x)\right)-\frac{1}{4} \log ^2(\tan (x)).$$

At this point, we multiply both sides of the Fourier-like series by $x$ and integrate from $x=0$ to $x=\pi/4$ that gives
$$\frac{1}{16} \color{blue}{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{ H_{2 n}}{n^3}}-\frac{5}{16}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{ H_n}{n^3}+\frac{3}{16}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_n}{n^3}$$
$$+\frac{\pi^2}{32}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\left(H_{2 n}-H_n-\log(2)\right)-\frac{7}{64} \log (2)\zeta (3)+\frac{75}{512}\zeta(4)$$
$$=\frac{1}{4} \int_0^{\pi/4} x\log ^2\left(\frac{1}{2} \sin (2 x)\right)\textrm{d}x-\frac{1}{4}\int_0^{\pi/4} x\log ^2(\tan (x))\textrm{d}x$$
$$=\frac{1}{16} \int_0^{\pi/2} x\log ^2\left(\frac{1}{2} \sin (x)\right)\textrm{d}x-\frac{1}{4}\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan(x)}{1+x^2}\log ^2(x)\textrm{d}x$$
$$=\frac{1}{16}\log ^2(2)\int_0^{\pi/2}x\textrm{d}x-\frac{1}{8}\log (2) \int_0^{\pi/2} x \log (\sin (x))\textrm{d}x +\frac{1}{16} \int_0^{\pi/2} x \log ^2(\sin (x))\textrm{d}x$$
$$+\frac{1}{32} \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } (-1)^{n-1}\frac{ H_n}{n^3}-\frac{1}{16} \color{blue}{\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } (-1)^{n-1} \frac{H_{2 n}}{n^3}},$$
because $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac{\arctan(x)}{1+x^2}\log^2(x) \textrm{d}x=\frac{1}{4} \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } (-1)^{n-1}\frac{ H_{2 n}}{n^3}-\frac{1}{8} \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } (-1)^{n-1}\frac{ H_n}{n^3}$, and then all reduces to
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{ H_{2 n}}{n^3}$$
$$=\frac{9}{8} \log ^2(2) \zeta (
2)-\frac{7}{16} \log (2)\zeta (3) +\frac{1}{2} \int_0^{\pi/2} x \log ^2(\sin (x))\textrm{d}x$$
$$+\frac{11}{4} \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } (-1)^{n-1}\frac{ H_n}{n^3}-\frac{3}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_n}{n^3}-\frac{\pi^2}{4}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\left(H_{2 n}-H_n-\log(2)\right)$$
$$+\frac{7}{8} \log (2)\zeta (3)-\frac{75}{64}\zeta(4),$$

and since we have that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1} \frac{H_n}{n^3}$$
$$=\frac{11}{4}\zeta(4)-\frac{7}{4}\log(2)\zeta(3)+\frac{1}{2}\log^2(2)\zeta(2)-\frac{1}{12}\log^4(2)-2 \operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right);$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_n}{n^3}=\frac{5}{4}\zeta(4);$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\left(H_{2 n}-H_n-\log(2)\right)=\log^2(2)-\frac{1}{2}\zeta(2);$$
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} x \log ^2(\sin (x))\textrm{d}x=\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{24}\log^4(2)+\frac{1}{2}\log^2(2)\zeta(2)-\frac{19}{32}\zeta(4),$$
where the first three result are found in the book, **(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series** (see pages $309$-$310$, $87$, eq. $3.45$, $250$, eq. $3.294$), and the fourth one is already calculated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3292272) (and also other ways are possible), we conclude that

> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{ H_{2 n}}{n^3}$$
> $$=\frac{195}{32}\zeta(4)+\frac{5}{4} \log ^2(2)\zeta(2)-\frac{35}{8}\log (2)\zeta (3) -\frac{5}{24} \log ^4(2)-5 \operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right).$$

Finally, to extract the second series, we use the relation already established in the book, **(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series**, Sect. $4.58$, page $313$,
$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{ H_{2 n}}{n^3}+\sum _{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{ H_{2 n}^{(2)}}{n^2}=2G^2+\frac{37}{64}\zeta(4),$$
that if we combine with the previous result, we obtain

> $$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{ H_{2 n}^{(2)}}{n^2}$$
> $$=2G^2-\frac{353}{64}\zeta(4)-\frac{5}{4} \log ^2(2)\zeta(2)+\frac{35}{8}\log (2)\zeta (3) +\frac{5}{24} \log ^4(2)+5 \operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right).$$

Comment: @User Thank you! I was in the process of editing. All fixed now.

Comment: (+1) Revolutionary indeed. This work deserves publishing for sure. Congrats to Cornel.