# Two hard integrals: $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log{(x)}\log{(1-x)}\log{(1+x^2)}}{x}dx$ and $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log^2{(x)}\log{(1+x^2)}}{1-x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals, special-functions

I found two integrals that seem hard to evaluate:
$$I_1=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log{(x)}\log{(1-x)}\log{(1+x^2)}}{x}dx$$
$$I_2=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log^2{(x)}\log{(1+x^2)}}{1-x}dx$$
I am just a beginner in logarithmic integral. So, I searched to find substitution like $x=\frac{1}{1+x}$, $x=\frac{1}{1-x}$, or $x=\frac{1-x}{1+x}$, but they didn't work.
Can I ask some ideas from every one? Thank you.

EDIT: After using Mathematica, with MZIntegrate paclet gives closed-form:

$$\begin{align}I_1&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log{(x)}\log{(1-x)}\log{(1+x^2)}}{x}dx\\&=G^2+\frac{5 \text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{4}+\frac{35}{32} \zeta (3) \log (2)-\frac{119 \pi ^4}{5760}+\frac{5 \log ^4(2)}{96}-\frac{5}{96} \pi ^2 \log ^2(2)\\I_2&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log^2{(x)}\log{(1+x^2)}}{1-x}dx\\&=2 G^2+\frac{35}{16} \zeta (3) \log (2)-\frac{199 \pi ^4}{5760}\end{align}$$
where $G$ is Catalan's constant.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha can't obtain closed forms for either integral. It numerically estimates them as $0.149762,\,0$. The latter, a clear bug (I wish I knew how to report it), is at odds with its plot of the integrand, shading an area that's obviously approximately $0.1$.

Comment: So, where did you find these two guys?

Comment: @J.G. Thank you, i searched MSE and found a paclet called MZIntegrate for Mathematica, and it can give closed form for these 2 integrals.

Comment: @Feng On Quora or somewhere i can't rememeber, i wrote the question for trying to solve it, and really forgot where it was.

Comment: @RobertLee I added closed form which is given by Mathematica. Thanks.

Comment: @OnTheWay If you are just a beginner of logarithmic integrals, you might want to start with easier problems, these two are not quite beginner level, but slick solutions should exist. Also, it would be good if you could provide link to the MMA paclet you used, so others can try it themselves.

Comment: @pisco https://www.researchgate.net/publication/357601353_Mathematica_package_MultipleZetaValues follow the instruction of this link. I can solve some logarithmic integrals, and can understand solution.

Comment: Related:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3763243/remarkable-logarithmic-integral-int-01-frac-log2-1-x-log2-x-log31x  This also provides a link to the Mathematica package MultipleZetaValues.  `MZIntegrate` is just a command within that package.

Comment: Why I can't download this package, I click that link (https://www.researchgate.net/publication/342344452) but re-direct to an empty page? @OnTheWay

Comment: @MathFail Here it is : https://www.researchgate.net/publication/357601353_Mathematica_package_MultipleZetaValues, scroll down, from drop down menu, click MultipleZetaValues-1.1.0.zip, and follow the instruction in .pdf.

Comment: I try to install it but it says: ZipGetFile::noentry: Requested file PacletInfo.m was not found in Zip file C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\MultipleZetaValues-1.1.0.paclet. @OnTheWay

Comment: @MathFail Here is how i did it: Extract the zip to any drive, remember where you extracted it, start Mathematica, type PacletInstall@
FileNameJoin[{"Drive name:", "folder name","MultipleZetaValues-1.1.0.paclet"}], close Mathematica and reopen it.
After that, to start this paclet: type <<MultipleZetaValues`, wait for a moment, and you can use MZIntegrate.

Comment: The substitution $x = e^{-t}$ would be the first thing I think of. Especially for that second integral, which immediately starts looking zeta-ish.

Comment: @KStarGamer, pisco. Yes, i just found out, thank you very much pisco for bringing to us a very helpful tool.

Answer (score 10):

The routine integrals $\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2t}{1-t}dt = 2\zeta(3)$,
$\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2t}{1+t}dt = \frac32\zeta(3)$,
$\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3t}{1-t}dt = -\frac{\pi^4}{15}$,
$\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2t}{1+t^2}dt =\frac{\pi^3}{16}$,
$\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t}{1+t^2}dt =-G$, and
$\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t}{1+t}dt =-\frac{\pi^2}{12}$ are used below without elaboration.

\begin{align}
I_2=&\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2x\ln(1+x^2)}{1-x}dx\\
=& \int_0^1\ln(1+x^2)\ d\left( \int_0^x \frac{\ln^2t}{1-t}dt\right)\\
=& \ \ln2 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2t}{1-t}dt
-\int_0^1\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\int_0^x\frac{\ln^2t}{1-t} \overset{t=xy}{dt}\\
=&\ 2\ln2\zeta(3) +2\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2xy}{1+y^2}\left(\frac{1+xy}{1+x^2}-\frac1{1-xy}\right)dxdy\tag1
\end{align}
Note that, with $\ln^2xy =\ln^2x +2\ln x\ln y +\ln^2 y$
\begin{align}
&\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{(1+xy)\ln^2xy}{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)}dxdy\\
=& \int_0^1 \int_0^1\frac{\ln^2x +2\ln x\ln y +\ln^2 y}{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)}+\frac1{16}\frac{\ln^2x +2\ln x\ln y +\ln^2 y}{(1+x)(1+y)}\ dxdy\\
=&\ 2G^2 +\frac3{16}\ln2\zeta(3)+\frac{37\pi^4}{1152}\\
\\ & \int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2xy}{(1+y^2)(1-xy)}\overset{x=t/y}{dx}dy\\
=& \ \frac12\int_0^1 d\left(\ln\frac{y^2}{1+y^2}\right)\int_0^y \frac{\ln^2t}{1-t}dt
\overset{ibp}=-\ln2\zeta(3)+\frac{\pi^4}{15}+\frac12I_2
\end{align}
Plug into (1) to obtain
\begin{align}
I_2 = &\ 2\ln2\zeta(3)+2 \left(2G^2 +\frac3{16}\ln2\zeta(3)+\frac{37\pi^4}{1152} \right)+2\ln2\zeta(3)-\frac{2\pi^4}{15}-I_2\\
=&\ 2G^2 +\frac{35}{16}\ln2\zeta(3)-\frac{199\pi^4}{5760}
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for the solution for one of them, i understood your ideas clearly.

Answer (score 7):

Just some remarks from a higher perspective. Integrals:
$$\tag{1} \int_0^1 f(x) dx$$
when $f(x)$ is one of
$$\small \frac{\log^n x \log(1+x^2)}{1\pm x},\frac{\log^{2n} x \log(1+x^2)}{1+x^2},\frac{x\log^{2n} x \log(1+x^2)}{1+x^2},\frac{\log^{2n} x \arctan x}{1- x},\frac{\log^{n} x \arctan x}{1+ x},\frac{x\log^{2n} x \arctan x}{1 + x^2},\frac{\log^{2n+1} x \arctan x}{1 + x^2},\frac{\log^{2n} x\log(1\pm x)}{1 + x^2},\frac{x\log^{2n+1}x \log(1\pm x)}{1 + x^2},\frac{\log^{2n}x \log(1\pm x) \log(1+x^2)}{x},\frac{\log^{2n+1}x \arctan x \log(1+x^2)}{x},\frac{\log^{2n+1}x \arctan x \log(1\pm x)}{x},\frac{\log^{2n+1} x \text{Li}_{2m}(x)}{1+x^2},
\frac{\log^{2n} x \text{Li}_{2m+1}(x)}{1+x^2},
\frac{x \log^{2n+1} x \text{Li}_{2m+1}(x)}{1+x^2} \text{  etc...}$$
all have results of form
$$\tag{2}\int_0^1 f(x) dx = \sum_{i=1}^{w} a_i L(i)L(w-i)$$
here $a_i \in \mathbb{Q}$, $L(s) =\zeta(s)$ or $\beta(s)$ are Riemann zeta or Dirichlet beta, $w$ is the weight of integrand, namely degree of numerator plus one.

---

OP's $I_2$ belongs to above cases; $I_1$ also, had the power of $\log$ were even; the odd power case is more difficult.

For $I_1$, the fact that MZIntegrate can do it already implies a mechanical proof exists. If you want magical/elegant solutions, perhaps [Conrad Valean](https://www.facebook.com/cornelioan.valean) or [Ali Shadhar](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/432085/ali-shadhar) can shed light on this. A highly non-trivial extension is $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log^3{(x)}\log{(1\pm x)}\log{(1+x^2)}}{x}dx$, you can put it into MZIntegrate to see what it looks like, I think Conrad and Ali have yet to found a solution to this one.

For example:
<sub>$$\int_0^1 \frac{\log ^5(x) \log \left(x^2+1\right) \arctan x}{x} dx = 720 \beta(8)-\frac{25 \pi ^5 \zeta (3)}{32}-\frac{15 \pi ^3 \zeta (5)}{2}-\frac{123825 \pi  \zeta (7)}{2048}$$
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\log^4 x \log(1+x)}{1+x^2} dx = \frac{7 \pi ^4 G}{30}+2 \pi ^2 \beta(4)-48 \beta(6)+\frac{5}{128} \pi ^5 \log (2)$$
$$\int_0^1 \frac{x \log^5 x \log(1-x)}{1+x^2} dx = -\frac{\pi ^4 \zeta (3)}{8}-\frac{75 \pi ^2 \zeta (5)}{128}+\frac{129495 \zeta (7)}{2048}-\frac{33}{512}\pi ^6 \log (2)$$
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\log^4 x \log(1-x) \log(1+x^2)}{x} dx = -\frac{5 \pi ^5 G}{32}-\frac{1}{2} 3 \pi ^3 \beta(4)-12 \pi  \beta(6)+\frac{121 \pi ^4 \zeta (3)}{2560}+\frac{105 \pi ^2 \zeta (5)}{512}+\frac{121557 \zeta (7)}{1024}$$</sub>

when weight $w\geq 7$, MZIntegrate is not able to evaluate them directly. I will add this functionality on the next update.

If one replaces $1+x^2$ occurring in $f(x)$ by $1+x+x^2$ or $1-x+x^2$ or $1+x^4$ etc, one obtain similar expressions, except now $L$ has to be other Dirichlet L-functions.

---

*Proof sketch*: for all cases $f(x)$ above, the integral $\int_0^1 f(x) dx$ can be converted to colored multiple zeta values (CMZVs) of depth 2 and level 4 and weight $w$. There is a result saying that whenever depth and weight of a CMZV satisfies certain parity condition, its real/imaginary part reduces to lower depths CMZVs. In our case, we have reduction into depth 1 CMZVs, which when level = 4 is simply $\zeta(s)$ or $\beta(s)$, giving $(2)$. QED.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, i am very sorry when i used MZIntegrate but didn't know it was created by you. What you posted above is really useful.

Comment: @OnTheWay No need to apologize, who created it is not that important anyway :)

Answer (score 4):

**Solutions by Cornel Ioan Valean**

It's straightforward to show that $\displaystyle \int_0^1 x^{n-1}\log(x)\log(1-x)\textrm{d}x=\frac{H_n}{n^2}+\frac{H_n^{(2)}}{n}-\zeta(2)\frac{1}{n}$, and this is easily  extracted by differentiating once with respect to $n$ the well-known result {with a Beta function (involving derivates) structure}, $\displaystyle\int_0^1 x^{n-1}\log(1-x)\textrm{d}x=-\frac{\psi(n+1)+\gamma}{n}$. Observe the latter result, when $n$ is a positive integer, may be put in the form with harmonic numbers, that is $\displaystyle\int_0^1 x^{n-1}\log(1-x)\textrm{d}x=-\frac{H_n}{n}$. The last integral form  can be found elementary calculated in **(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series**, page $59$.

Returning to **the first main integral** and using the previous results, we get
$$\int_0^1\frac{\log{(x)}\log{(1-x)}\log{(1+x^2)}}{x}\textrm{d}x=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{1}{n}\int_0^1x^{2n-1}\log(x)\log(1-x)\textrm{d}x 
$$
$$=-\frac{1}{2}\zeta(2)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1} \frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_{2n}}{n^3}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_{2n}^{(2)}}{n^2}$$
$$=G^2-\frac{5}{16}\log^2(2)\zeta(2)+\frac{35}{32}\log(2)\zeta(3)-\frac{119}{64}\zeta(4)+\frac{5}{96}\log^4(2)+\frac{5}{4}\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right),$$
and  the last equality follows by using the fact that the last two series are computed [here, and they are some of the most difficult to calculate harmonic series (of low weight class,  $\le7$) in the mathematical literature.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3803762)

For **the second main integral**, we have the more general result,

\begin{equation*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_{2n}^{(m)}}{n}=\frac{(-1)^m}{(m-1)!}\int_0^1\frac{\displaystyle \log^{m-1}(x)\log\left(\frac{1+x^2}{2}\right)}{1-x}\textrm{d}x
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
=m\zeta (m+1)- 2^{-m} \left(1-2^{-m+1}\right) \log(2 ) \zeta (m) -\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\beta(k+1)\beta(m-k)
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
-\sum_{k=1}^{m-2}2^{- m-1}(1-2^{-k})(1-2^{-m+k+1}) \zeta (k+1)\zeta (m-k),
\end{equation*}
where $H_n^{(m)}=1+\frac{1}{2^m}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n^m}$ represents the $n$th generalized harmonic number of order $m$,
$\zeta$ denotes the Riemann zeta function and $\beta$ designates the Dirichlet beta function.

A very simple solution may be found in [this answer that exploits the symmetry in double integrals](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3236584).

**End of story**

Comment: Can you explain more from "Returning to the first main integral and using the previous results, we get", i understood the rest but from this i don't know how to derive to get your result. Thanks.

Comment: @OnTheWay Essentially, I used that $\displaystyle \frac{\log(1+x^2)}{x}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^{2n}}{n}$ and then I employed the first logarithmic integral stated in the beginning of the solution. Observe that there is a link that brings you  to a page where the two difficult harmonic series are calculated. Here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3803424/how-to-find-sum-n-1-infty-frac-1nh-2nn3-and-sum-n-1-infty-f/3803762#3803762

Comment: Awsome, i saw and understood completely, thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Express the first integral via integration by parts in terms of the second and a third integral
$$
I_1=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln x\ln(1-x)\ln (1+x^2)}{x}dx=\frac12I_2 -I_3\tag1$$
where
\begin{align}
I_2=&\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^2x\ln (1+x^2)}{1-x}dx
= 2G^2 +\frac{35}{16}\ln2\zeta(3)-\frac{199\pi^4}{5760}\\
I_3=& \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x\ln^2 x\ln(1-x)}{1+x^2}dx
=-\frac54\text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{13 \pi ^4}{3840}+\frac{5\pi^2}{96} \ln ^22-\frac{5 }{96}\ln ^42
\end{align}

Similarly to $I_2$, $I_3$ is relatively manageable and is evaluated in the Appendix. Substitute above into (1) to obtain
$$I_1=\frac54\text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+ G^2+\frac{35}{32} \ln2\zeta (3) -\frac{119 \pi ^4}{5760}-\frac{5\pi^2}{96} \ln ^22+\frac{5 }{96}\ln ^42
$$

---

Appendix: (to be completed)
\begin{align}
I_3=\frac18 \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^2 x\ln (1-x)}{1+x}\ \overset{x\to x^2}{dx}
 - \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x\ln^2x\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}dx\\
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^2x\ln(1-x)}{1+x}dx=&\ 
-4\text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) +\frac{\pi^4}{90}+\frac{\pi^2}6\ln^22-\frac16\ln^42\\
\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x\ln^2x\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}dx=&\
\frac34 \text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-\frac{23\pi^4}{11520}-\frac{\pi^2}{32}\ln^22+\frac1{32}\ln^42
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you, i can't wait for being seen your appendix, really awsome sir.